# Jquery autocomplete dropdown not working in dynamic build textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build a search textbox dynamically and i want to do autocomplete search . Below is my code,

```
function getEmp(){
   $('#itemSearch').autocomplete({
     "source":function(request, response) { 
      var textInput = document.getElementById('a');
      textInput.value = textInput.value.replace(/^\s+/,"");
      var jqxhr = $.getJSON( baseurl +'test/search-emp', {
       cName :$("#a").val(),
     },response);
      jqxhr.success(function() { 

     });
    },
   "select":function(e, ui){
    },
    "minLength":1,"autoFill":true,"showHeader":true});

  }
```

I got the ajax result,but dropdown is not visible in autocomplete search.Please provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

according to document ; http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Your ajax must return an array or like ...

```
 [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

Prepare an api or something return documented kind a data vie Get
this source must use 'term' parameter
then put this to page YOUR_AJAX_URL must point your api...

```
       $( function() {
           $("#itemSearch" ).autocomplete({
             source: "YOUR_AJAX_URL",
             minLength: 2,
             select: function( event, ui ) {                   
               alert(ui.item.value);
             }
           });
         } );
```

ps. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote at here you can investigate developer tools in chrome (or similar)